# Running Kibana and Elasticsearch under Mongrel2

Tags: https, proxy, elasticsearch, kibana, mongrel2

I have a Vagrant VM running Elasticsearch and Kibana. Kibana is currently  being served by Mongrel2 as per the following configuration

```
kibana_directory = Dir(base='kibana/',
                    index_file='index.html',
                    default_ctype='text/plain')

myhost = Host(name = 'localhost', routes = {
  '/logs/': kibana_directory
})
```

Elasticsearch is running on port 9200. When I try view Kibana, however, it doesn't load properly, giving me the following error in the browser

```
[blocked] The page at 'https://dev.demo.vm/logs/' was loaded over HTTPS, but 
ran insecure content from 'http://dev.demo.vm:9200/_nodes': this content should 
also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

The problem seems obvious enough, Mongrel2 is serving content over `https` but Elasticsearch is queried over `http`, so Kibana (served over `https`) cannot communicate with it. I want to keep the `https` for Mongrel2, but I don't know what to do to get Kibana working. Should I be using proxies of some sort with Mongrel2? Is there a straightforward solution?